# Optional block based on variable

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm writing sort of wrapper module for `azurerm_storage_account`.

`azurerm_storage_account` has optional block

```
static_website {
  index_document = string
  error_404_document = string
}
```

I want to set it based on variable and I'm not really sure how can I do that? Conditional operators don't really work for blocks (e.g. `static_website = var.disable ? null : { .. }` )

Or do blocks work in such a way that if I'd set `index_document` and `error_404_document` to `null` it'd be the same as not setting `static_website` block altogether?

`azurerm@2.x`

`TF@0.12.x`

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I think you  can use [dynamic block](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks) for that. Basically, when the `disable` is `true`, no `static_website` will be created. Otherwise, one `static_website` block is going to be constructed.

For example, the modified code could be:

```
  dynamic "static_website" {

    for_each = var.disable == true ? toset([]) : toset([1])

    content {
        index_document = string
        error_404_document = string
    }
  }
```

You could also try with [splat](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#splat-expressions) to check if `disable` has value or is null:

```
  dynamic "static_website" {

    for_each = var.disable[*]

    content {
        index_document = string
        error_404_document = string
    }
  }
```

In the above examples, you may need to adjust conditions based on what values `var.disable` can actually have.